# Cannot read ('select') and write ('update') in same postgres connection?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, select

I am using the code below to take user input (name, password) and compare against a postgres database to provide a 'login' functionality.  I seem to be able to take the user input and locate the required information in the database without an issue.  My problem occurs when I attempt to write/update information to the database line ...I get a program crash and disconnection.  My script includes 2 queries, one for the 'read' and another for the 'write/update' (which is commented out).

Using the included code throws an error.  However if I remove/comment out the second query (which is used to write/update the database) the error does not happen.  The code I provided shows that routine commented out and as such the error is not thrown.  The two queries involved are the one utilizing the 'query' variable ('read') and the one using the 'mods' variable ('write/update')

```
require('dotenv').config();
const url = require('url')
var pg = require('pg');
const params = url.parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
const auth = params.auth.split(':');

const config = {
 user: auth[0],
 password: auth[1],
 host: params.hostname,
 port: params.port,
 database: params.pathname.split('/')[1],
 max: 20,
 idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
 connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
 ssl: false
};

var pool = new pg.Pool(config);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

//Use Express module
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var io = require("socket.io");  //web socket external module

// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })



//Respond to POST from login form
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {  

 var now = new Date().getTime();

 //**Query PostGres database...

 var conString = "postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/mydatabase";
 var client = new pg.Client(conString);

 const query = {
  text: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = $1 AND pass = $2", 
  values: [String(req.body.user), String(req.body.password)]
 };

 var mods = "UPDATE users SET login = '" + now + "' WHERE name = '" + String(req.body.user) + "' AND pass ='" + String(req.body.password) + "';";

  pool.connect(function(err,client,done) {
     if(err){
     console.log("not able to get connection "+ err);
     res.status(400).send(err);
     } 

   client.query(query, function(err, result) {   
//   //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
//   done(); 
    if(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
    }

    if (typeof result.rows[0] === "undefined") {
    console.log("No user/password determined in DB for login attempt");

    } else {

    console.log(result.rows[0].name)
    console.log(result.rows[0].pass)
    console.log(result.rows[0].status)

     if (result.rows[0].status === "active") {
     console.log("User is determined to be ACTIVE in database");
     req.session.user = String(req.body.user);

     console.log("req.session.user is " + req.session.user);


      if (typeof req.session.user != "undefined") {

      console.log("Session User is DEFINED...!");
      console.log("Dashboard Accessed");

//       //callback...for WRITING into database...!
//
//       client.query(mods, function(err, result) {   
//    //   //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
//    //   done(); 
//        if(err){
//        console.log(err);
//        //res.status(400).send(err);
//        }
//
//       });

       res.render('_user_steps',);

       console.log("SECONDARY WRITE AND OPERATION COMPLETE...!");

      } else {
      console.log("Session User is NOT DEFINED...!");

      }  //req.session.user is defined...OR NOT...


     } else {
     console.log("User is determined to be INACTIVE in database");
     }  //User ACTIVE...OR NOT...

    }  //user/password is 'undefined' (NOT found in database)...OR NOT 

   console.log(result.rows[0]);
   client.end();
   });
  });

});
```

Is it possible to do a read and write operation within the same pool connection without crashing the script...?  What exactly would be causing such a behavior?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm just going to stop you right here... Please read up on proper login authentication methods before you try and solve this. 1. Do not store user's passwords in plain text. Ever. 2. You're using direct input from the user in your sql queries, that's a big no no. If you continue down this path you will have nothing but problems. Search for "user authentication best practices" and also [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/12-best-practices-for-user-account) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I do sanitize the user input before calling the database queries, I just did not include that in my sample code as that is not the issue I am having.  As far as the user passwords I can later change that to a similar method I am using for the database connection, that is using the dotenv approach.  Those are secondary issues right now to getting the queries functional.

Comment: What do environment variables have to do with user passwords? Nothing. If you're not hashing and salting passwords then you are not doing authentication correctly. Stop trying to reinvent the wheel, there are dozens of auth libraries available which get this correct.

Comment: Just trying to understand why the original issue occurs and learn how to do certain routines using original code...therefore I find 're-inventing the wheel' to be useful.  I will likely try that Firebase option on that link you sent me.  In addition at this point there are no real security issues since I do not put any critical data in a database anyway therefore nothing of value is exposed...perhaps later down the road, which is why I want to sharpen my Node.js skills more finely.